# Getting Login failed with SQL Sever database using MVC4 web app

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, server

I'm learning ASP.NET MVC and I got a issue of connection between my application and a SQL Server database on server.

I get this message

> Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used
>   with Windows authentication.

I have connection string in my local host which is working:

```
<add name="myAppEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/App_Data.myapp.csdl|res://*/App_Data.MyApp.ssdl|res://*/App_Data.MyApp.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=myDb;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I have connection string in my live Server which is Not working:

```
<add name="myAppEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/App_Data.myapp.csdl|res://*/App_Data.MyApp.ssdl|res://*/App_Data.MyApp.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=myDb;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;User Id=sa;password=password@$!;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I want to make a connection with SQL Server database. How can I fix this to open connection between my ASP.NET MVC app and SQL Server?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string is going to look for a SQL server instance with instance name `SQLEXPRESS` in the same machine and the process running your MVC app should have access to this db server and myDb database.

Typically in production environment, your db server name would be different than the minimal SQLEXPRESS which you use in your local development enviroment. You should find out your SQL server instant name and user credenitals to access that and update your connection string to use those.

The specific parts you need to update are

**data source** : replace with your production sql express instance name.

**initial catalog** : your db name. It could be same as what you had in your development environment.

Looks like you have a specific username and password for accessing your db in your production SQL server, you should get rid of windows authentication in your connection string and use the username password combo.

For ex :

```
<add name="myAppEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/App_Data.myapp.csdl
|res://*/App_Data.MyApp.ssdl|res://*/App_Data.MyApp.msl;provider=System.Data
.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=someproductionservername;
initial catalog=myDb;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
User Id=sa;password=password@$!;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

***Side note*** : It may not be a good idea to use the sa user. You should create a new user-password combo for your app.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove Integrated security setting from the second string because it looks like you want to login with sa